# Gmail IMAP is sometimes returning bad results for fetch

Tags: python, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I'm using python to connect to gmail via IMAP.

When I do a fetch for a bunch of uids, the results sometimes contain a couple weird ones tacked on to the end.

This bug appears intermittent and started appearing sometime in the last week or so.

For example I do a fetch like:

```
>>>import imaplib
>>>conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
>>># authenticate etc
>>>conn.uid('fetch', '12,13', '(X-GM-THRID)')
```

I sometimes get a result like:

```
>>>['1 (X-GM-THRID 123123123123 UID 12)', 
    '2 (X-GM-THRID 123123123123 UID 13)', 
    '365022 (UID 601722 FLAGS (\\Seen))']
```

(Line breaks added for readability, ids changed from original, normally I'm fetching far more than two.)

This is pretty weird. I haven't requested anything at all about the extra message. Sometimes it's there, sometimes not. No matter what fields I fetch, the extra result (I've only ever seen one or two) never contains them, and only contains the FLAGS info.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: what is the type of `conn`?

Comment: imaplib.IMAP4_SSL - I've edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following was posted in the IMAP Protocol mailing list earlier this week:

"As of yesterday [Monday October 7th], Gmail now supports reporting flags changes anywhere we would report new/expunged messages (ie, most places its allowed by the protocol, but definitely during IDLE).  Its only enabled for gmail.com users at the moment, Google Apps users will follow in a week or so, assuming we don't find any issues."

However, there are apparently issues with the new functionality because today they said it is being rolled back:

"We're seeing several reports of programs not expected extra FETCH responses, which we rolled out on Monday.  We're rolling back soon, since older versions of a very popular client are having issues (though not to our knowledge with this part of things)."

-Rick

Answer (score 2):

Gmail is sending you unsolicited `FLAGS` updates (because someone changed the message remotely).  These aren't in response to your request, but IMAP allows the server to send you any* information at any time.  Many servers will save these unsolicited responses for `IDLE` or `NOOP` responses, but apparently Gmail does not wish to wait.

However, until recently (apparently?) Gmail did not send flag updates at all, only EXPUNGEs.

*: There are a few rules about which responses can be sent when to avoid race conditions, but this isn't one of those.